# How to reverse a dictionary in Julia?

Tags: dictionary, julia

If I have a dictionary such as

```
my_dict = Dict(
    "A" => "one",
    "B" => "two",
    "C" => "three"
  )
```

What's the best way to reverse the key/value mappings?

Comment: Do you have to worry about two different keys mapping to the same value, or not?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way would be to use a comprehension to build the new dictionary by iterating over the key/value pairs, swapping them along the way:

```
julia> Dict(value => key for (key, value) in my_dict)
Dict{String,String} with 3 entries:
  "two"   => "B"
  "one"   => "A"
  "three" => "C"
```

When swapping keys and values, you may want to keep in mind that if `my_dict` has duplicate values (say `"A"`), then the new dictionary may have fewer keys. Also, the value located by key `"A"` in the new dictionary may not be the one you expect (Julia's dictionaries do not store their contents in any easily-determined order).

Answer (score 15):

Assuming that you don't have to worry about repeated values colliding as keys, you could use `map` with `reverse`:

```
julia> my_dict = Dict("A" => "one", "B" => "two", "C" => "three")
Dict{String,String} with 3 entries:
  "B" => "two"
  "A" => "one"
  "C" => "three"

julia> map(reverse, my_dict)
Dict{String,String} with 3 entries:
  "two"   => "B"
  "one"   => "A"
  "three" => "C"
```

Comment: That's the best answer!

Comment: @DSM: How can you do this for Julia v1.x?

Comment: I think this does not work in Julia Version 1.1.1. I get an error "map is not defined on dictionaries".

Comment: Use `collect` on `my_dict` first for Julia >= v1.x

Answer (score 5):

made this a while back for dictionaries that may have clashing values

```
function invert_dict(dict, warning::Bool = false)
    vals = collect(values(dict))
    dict_length = length(unique(vals))

    if dict_length < length(dict)
        if warning
            warn("Keys/Vals are not one-to-one")
        end 

        linked_list = Array[]

        for i in vals 
            push!(linked_list,[])
        end 

        new_dict = Dict(zip(vals, linked_list))

        for (key,val) in dict 
            push!(new_dict[val],key)
        end
    else
        key = collect(keys(dict))

        counter = 0
        for (k,v) in dict 
            counter += 1
            vals[counter] = v
            key[counter] = k
        end
        new_dict = Dict(zip(vals, key))
    end 

    return new_dict
end
```

using this if if a key becomes duplicate, you'll have a list with all values, so no data will be lost, i.e

```
julia> a = [1,2,3]
julia> b = ["a", "b", "b"]

julia> Dict(zip(a,b))
Dict{Int64,String} with 3 entries:
  2 => "b"
  3 => "b"
  1 => "a"

julia> invert_dict(ans)
Dict{String,Array} with 2 entries:
  "b" => Any[2,3]
  "a" => Any[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

In Julia 1.x (assuming a bijection between keys and values):

```
julia> D = Dict("A" => "one", "B" => "two", "C" => "three")
Dict{String,String} with 3 entries:
  "B" => "two"
  "A" => "one"
  "C" => "three"

julia> invD = Dict(D[k] => k for k in keys(D))
Dict{String,String} with 3 entries:
  "two"   => "B"
  "one"   => "A"
  "three" => "C"
```

Otherwise:

```
julia> D = Dict("A" => "one", "B" => "three", "C" => "three")
Dict{String,String} with 3 entries:
  "B" => "three"
  "A" => "one"
  "C" => "three"

julia> invD = Dict{String,Vector{String}}()
Dict{String,Array{String,1}} with 0 entries

julia> for k in keys(D)
         if D[k] in keys(invD)
           push!(invD[D[k]],k)
         else
           invD[D[k]] = [k]
         end
       end

julia> invD
Dict{String,Array{String,1}} with 2 entries:
  "one"   => ["A"]
  "three" => ["B", "C"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another good idea is what is done in this post:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-something-like-reversed-dict-findall-x-x-house-cc-is-to-slow/16443

Particularly, I liked a lot the solution, due to `@ExpandingMan`:

```
dict = Dict(rand(Int, 10^5) .=> rand(Int, 10^5))
rdict = Dict(values(dict) .=> keys(dict))
```

or the one from `@bennedich`

```
dict = Dict(rand(Int, 10^5) .=> rand(Int, 10^5))
rdict = Dict(v => k for (k,v) in dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

DSM answer adapted with bluesmoon comment becomes (checked in Julia 1.9):

```
julia> my_dict = Dict("A" => "one", "B" => "two", "C" => "three")
Dict{String, String} with 3 entries:
  "B" => "two"
  "A" => "one"
  "C" => "three"
julia> Dict(map(reverse, collect(my_dict)))
Dict{String,String} with 3 entries:
  "two"   => "B"
  "one"   => "A"
  "three" => "C"
```

Notice that `map(reverse, collect(my_dict))` has type `Vector{Pair{String, String}}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using BenchmarkTools
dic = Dict(zip(rand(10000),rand(10000)))
@benchmark Dict(map(reverse,collect(dic))) #403 us
@benchmark Dict(dic[i]=> i for i in keys(dic)) #2.84 ms
@benchmark Dict(reverse(i) for i in dic) #361 us
@benchmark Dict(value => key for (key, value) in dic) #351 us
@benchmark Dict(values(dic) .=> keys(dic)) #426 us
```