# Create a dictionary using "if... else" in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, if-statement, julia

I'm working with a sample CSV file that lists nursing home residents' DOBs and DODs. I used those fields to calculate their age at death, and now I'm trying to create a dictionary that "bins" their age at death into groups. I'd like the bins to be 1-25, 26-50, 51-75, and 76-100.

Is there a concise way to make a Dict(subject_id, age, age_bin) using "if... else" syntax?
For example: (John, 76, "76-100"), (Moira, 58, "51-75").

So far I have:

```
#import modules
using CSV
using DataFrames
using Dates

# Open, read, write desired files 
input_file = open("../data/FILE.csv", "r")
output_file = open("FILE_output.txt", "w")

# Use to later skip header line
file_flag = 0

for line in readlines(input_file)
    if file_flag==0
        global file_flag = 1
        continue
    end

    # Define what each field in FILE corresponds to
    line_array = split(line, ",")
    subject_id = line_array[2]
    gender = line_array[3]
    date_of_birth = line_array[4]
    date_of_death = line_array[5]

    # Get yyyy-mm-dd only (first ten characters) from fields 4 and 5:
    date_birth = date_of_birth[1:10]
    date_death = date_of_death[1:10]

    # Create DateFormat; use to calculate age
    date_format = DateFormat("y-m-d")
    age_days = Date(date_death, date_format) - Date(date_birth, date_format)
    age_years = round(Dates.value(age_days)/365.25, digits=0)

    # Use "if else" statement to determine values
    keys = age_years
    function values()
        if age_years <= 25
            return "0-25"
        elseif age_years <= 50
            return "26-50"
        elseif age_years <= 75
            return "51-75"
        else age_years < 100
            return "76-100"
        end
    end
    values()

    # Create desired dictionary
    age_death_dict = Dict(zip(keys, values()))

end
```

Edit: or is there a better way to approach this using DataFrames?

Comment: You can use `cut` from CategoricalArrays.jl although it will not create a `Dict`, but just bin the vector directly. I am not sure if this is what you would want.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, " is there a concise way using if/else" -- probably not, given that you have 5 cases (age ranges) you have to account for. Suppose you have names and ages in two separate lists (which I assume you generate from your example code, although I can't see the input CSVs):

```
julia> name = ["John", "Mary", "Robert", "Cindy", "Beatrice"];
julia> ages = [24, 73, 75, 69, 90];
julia> function bin_age_ifelse(a)
           if a<1
               return "Invalid age"
           elseif 1<=a<=25
               return "1-25"
           elseif 25<a<=50
               return "26-50"
           elseif 50<a<=75
               return "51-75"
           else
               return "76-100"
           end
       end
bin_age_ifelse (generic function with 1 method)


julia> binned_ifelse = Dict([n=>[a, bin_age_ifelse(a)] for (n,a) in zip(name, ages)])
Dict{String, Vector{Any}} with 5 entries:
  "John"     => [24, "1-25"]
  "Mary"     => [73, "51-75"]
  "Beatrice" => [90, "76-100"]
  "Robert"   => [75, "51-75"]
  "Cindy"    => [69, "51-75"]
```

Here's an option for the binning function to avoid if/else syntax, although there are probably yet more elegant ways to do it:

```
julia> function bin_age(a)
           bins = [1:25, 26:50, 51:75, 76:100]
           for b in bins
               if a in b
                   return "$(b[1])-$(b[end])"
               end
           end
        end
bin_age (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bin_age(84)
"76-100"
```

I've taken some liberties with the format of the answer, using the name as the key, since your original question describes a dict format that doesn't really make sense in Julia. If you'd like to have the keys be the age ranges, you could construct the dictionary above and then invert it [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57603886/4084825) (with some modification since the values above have two entries).

If you don't care about name, age, or age range being a key, then I would suggest using DataFrames.jl:

```
julia> using DataFrames
  
julia> d = DataFrame(name=name, age=ages, age_range=[bin_age(a) for a in ages])
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ name      age    age_range 
     │ String    Int64  String    
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ John         24  1-25
   2 │ Mary         73  51-75
   3 │ Robert       75  51-75
   4 │ Cindy        69  51-75
   5 │ Beatrice     90  76-100
```